# Windows Phone equivalent to Android's WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest or iOS's NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I've been tasked with building Android, iOS and Windows Phone wrappers for a web based app.

One of the key requirements is that certain assets are bundled within the apps (such as images, CSS and JavaScript files) to reduce bandwidth and help increase responsiveness while still pulling HTML (and any missing assets) over the internet. To do this I need to somehow intercept the requests made in the native browser components of each platform.

In Android I can intercept the requests by overriding the WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest method and then substituting local data from the apps filesystem if the requested file is determined to exist and the files extension ends in either ".css", ".jpg", ".png" or ".js". If not, the asset is pulled over the internet as usual.

Under iOS I can intercept the requests by creating an object inheriting from the NSURLCache object and overriding the cachedResponseForRequest method, once again substituting local data from the apps filesystem if the requested file is determined to exist and the files extension ends in either ".css", ".jpg", ".png" or ".js". If not, the asset is pulled over the internet as usual.

Both of these wrappers are working as expected. The CSS, images and JavaScript files are confirmed as successfully being pulled and executed from the local assets when the respective files are present.

What I need to do now is build the equivalent for Windows Phone, but so far I have not managed to work out how to even intercept the requests made by the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser object.

I've looked all over for this but so far have found nothing useful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?